# Can't find and change Keyframes in Joint Take

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm new to Blender.

I bought a .blend file with an animated bird. I want to extend the animation and change it, but I don't understand where to find the keyframes. There is just one Keyframe line, but when i delete this, the animation is still going on. Couldn't find any information to "Takes" …

[image]

Thank you for you help in advance.

Comment: Hello could you please share the armature only so that we can take a look?

Comment: Sure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cx7PYZZWGMJPv9PB9DDpVYOnOA0r9Ntv/view?usp=share_link Thank you!

Comment: in the file you share, as soon as I select the armature, I can see all the keyframes relative to the armature object transforms and you can also see the bones keyframes if you select a bone in Pose mode, if you disable the Only Show Selected option of the Dope Sheet you'll see all the keyframes without having to select the bones

Comment: Aj! Thats it. Thank you so much! Have a nice evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just need to unfold the tracks on the left panel, you'll see all the keyframes relative to the armature transform. You can also see the bones keyframes if you select a bone in *Pose* mode, if you disable the *Only Show Selected* option of the *Dope Sheet* you'll see all the keyframes without having to select any bone.

[image]